# Range with variables as Input in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, variables, range

I am trying to pass a varible in Range but I am not able to, so the whole question is, I have two varibales a and b where values can be changed. now I want to select this range, but I am not able to select it as a range in VBA.

```
a  = ActiveCell.Address  ' suppose it returns me A3 

b = ActiveCell.Offset(20, 0).Address  ' suppose it returns me A23

Set d = range("a:b")  ' here i want to select A3:A23, but I am not able to 

d.select
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You suppressed `a` and `b` in the range statement with quotes. They're being read as literals. Unquote them.

```
a  = ActiveCell.Address  ' suppose it returns me A3  
b = ActiveCell.Offset(20, 0).Address  ' suppose it returns me A23
Set d = range(a & ":" & b)  ' here i want to select A3:A23, but I am not able to 

d.select
```

Comment: Pretty awesome, sorry for my dumbness

Answer (score 1):

Small mistakes. Try this.

```
a = ActiveCell.Address  'Get A3 

b = ActiveCell.Offset(20, 0).Address  'Get A23

Range(a, b).Select  'Select A3:A23
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set d = Range(a, b)` should do it. You know that `Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(20, 0)).Select` does the same? Also, you shouldn't need to select a range, if you want to copy for example, you would just use `Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(20, 0)).Copy`